# PHP RegEx create an associative array based on pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
$str = '<td class="title">Genre:</td><td class="detail"><a href="/en-us/store/browse/action">   Action   </a></td></tr>';
$str2 = '<td class="title">Release Date:</td><td class="detail">   January 13 2009  </td></tr>';
```

I need to get an associative array structured like this:

```
$arr[$title] = $detail;
```

My problem is not the pattern itself, but how to create an array. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regexp is like this

```
$re = '~<td class="title">(.+?):</td><td class="detail">(.+?)</td>~';
```

then you can simply do

```
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
$arr[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
```

Do note however, that regexes is not the best way to parse html.

Comment: And what is the best way to parse html?

Comment: @Xriuk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php